# Take the sum of a list as variable and edit it at runtime

Tags: c#, subtraction

I'm trying to calculate the end value of a specific variable that depends whether a checkbox is checked. This is however dynamically done.

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

The example above works fine but it starts going wrong when I start to uncheck the check boxes. It subtracts by the double amount of the time and I have no idea why:

[image]

My Code (`TimeSpent` is the variable that I want to have at the end):

Class

```
public class Activity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int IncidentID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int TimeSpent { get; set; }
    public static int StartX { get; set; } = 10;
    public static int StartY { get; set; } = 10;

    private TextBox textBox = null;

    private CheckBox checkBox = null;

    public Activity(int iD, int incidentID, string description, int timeSpent)
    {
        this.ID = iD;
        this.IncidentID = incidentID;
        this.Description = description;
        this.TimeSpent = timeSpent;
    }

    public Activity()
    { }

    public bool isChecked() {
        return checkBox.Checked;
    }

    public void setTimeSpent(int timeSpent) {
        this.TimeSpent = timeSpent;
        textBox.Text = timeSpent.ToString();
    }

    public int getTimeSpent()
    {
        return Int32.Parse(textBox.Text);
    }

    public void DrawToForm(Panel p)
    {    
        var label = new Label();
        textBox = new TextBox();
        checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.Checked = true;
        textBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 20);
        label.Text = Description.ToString();
        label.AutoSize = true;
        textBox.Text = TimeSpent.ToString();
        label.Left = StartX;
        label.Top = StartY;
        StartX += 430;// Move position to right
        textBox.Left = StartX;
        textBox.Top = StartY;
        StartX += 160;// Move position to right
        checkBox.Left = StartX;
        checkBox.Top = StartY;
        StartX = 10;// Reset to start
        StartY += 50;// Move position to down
        p.Controls.Add(label);
        p.Controls.Add(textBox);
        p.Controls.Add(checkBox);
    }
}
```

GUI:

```
private void Btn_Validate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    tb_TotalTime.Text = calculateTotalTime().ToString();
}

public int calculateTotalTime()
{
    int total = 0;
    foreach (Activity a in activities)
    {                  
        if(a.isChecked())
        {
            total += a.getTimeSpent();
        }else
        {
            total -= a.getTimeSpent();
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Why is subtracting not done correctly?

Comment: In the pictures everything looks ok. What is the concrete problem?

Comment: You're adding when it's check and subtracting when it isn't so -5-5+5 equals -5.  I think you just want the addition so remove the `else`.

Comment: It is doing correct calculation. For two unchecked checkboxes it becomes -10 and for one checked checkbox its 5 and sum of them becomes -5. What should be the result as per your expectation? You should not do subtraction if you want result to be 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You subtract when the checkbox is not checked:

```
if(a.isChecked())
{
    total += a.getTimeSpent();
}
else
{
    total -= a.getTimeSpent();// << THIS
}
```

So with the setup of your 2nd image (top 2 unchecked bottom one checked) you do this:

```
0 - 5 - 5 + 5 = -5
```

The 0 comes from the default value of `Total (int)`

---

To fix this you could just remove the `else` clause as you don't need to subtract billable time *ever*.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought, that this is the problem. That wouldn't be a coding problem at all. More a problem of common sense

Comment: @TimSchmelter because total is 0 at first. Then all non checked activities times get subtracted. first is 5, second is 5 and third is five. First and second aren't checked. Sums up to 0 - 5 - 5 + 5 = -5.

Comment: @TimSchmelter How do you come to that conclusion? Makes no sense at all

Comment: seems like he got it now

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @KahnKah No problem, best solution to these problems is go through the code as if you're explaining it. When you would get to the `-` part you would have been like "That does... uhm... that shouldn't be there" (google rubber duck debugging). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You should remove subtracting at all.
So change it to :

```
if(a.isChecked())
{
     total += a.getTimeSpent();
}
```

You have `total=0`, you have not added all values before calculating. So you don't need subtracting.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't noticing this

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is add if Check subtract if unchecked. Your logic should be add if Checked only.

```
private void Btn_Validate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        tb_TotalTime.Text = calculateTotalTime().ToString();
    }

    public int calculateTotalTime()
    {
        int total = 0;
        foreach (Activity a in activities)
        {

            if (a.isChecked())
            {
                total += a.getTimeSpent();
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much